# How to recover Win8 laptop from that will not boot?

Tags: windows-8, boot, system-recovery

I have a Lenovo Twist running Win 8.1 Preview that came with Win8.
If I did not create a recovery disc when I got my computer, is there still a way to recover it from a disc, and will this erase my files?

By the way, I am getting a 2100 error.

Answer (score 1):

If you reinstall your OS, you (most likely) will wipe your HDD, and take out your files in the process of reinstalling.

You can still reinstall your OS, but if you do not have the recovery disc, means you can't just simply follow the recovery process (which will re-install your OS, install all drivers, and all related software that comes with the Twist as if it was unboxed the first time).

By installing the OS manually (using your own Windows OS disc) then you will need to find the drivers manually (from Lenovo Website).

You can access the data, if you have a Linux LiveCD (or LiveUSB) that allows you to boot an OS from the CD / USB. Once you can boot using a LiveCD, you will be able to check the content of your HDD in your laptop - and hopefully copy your data out into a USB disk, or USB HDD. After that, you can start the recovery / full reinstallation process.

Good luck with it.

Comment: When you say LiveCD or LiveUSB, can I get one or do I need to already have made it?

Comment: You need to create one.. (I don't think anyone selling one) .. maybe your friend's computer to create an Ubuntu LiveCD or something..?